# DNS: external mail - webserver down

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

I'm currently running a small plesk server with a couple of domains. 
I configure all DNS settings of a domain in a custom "zonefile" of the company providing the server (hetzner), stored on hetzner nameservers.

Suppose my (plesk) webserver goes down for domain mydomain.com and mydomain.com has 2 mx records defined, pointing to other mail servers (exchange), then will mailing keep on working?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - that's the point of having nameservers separate from webservers. As long as your hosting company's nameservers are up, mail won't stop.

Also, even if your mail servers should be unreachable, as long as there are correct nameserver and MX records, any sender systems should just queue the mail on their servers and retry the periodically.

Comment: +1 Also, there are free secondary DNS services out there (BuddyNS is who I use, but there are others). Other mail servers will only queue the e-mails for a limited amount of time, usually a day or two.

Comment: Any competent hosting company will have their nameservers on separate AS's to make sure that at least one will always be reachable, so as long as you use a reputable one you should be safe. (And they only queue a couple of days nowadays? I'm feeling my age; back when I was working mailservers it'd be up to a week...)